# Firebase or Google integration conflict error

Tags: android, firebase

I am integrating Firebase, Google Play services, google-auth in my app.
Firebase messaging, firebase analytics, firebase iid, google services all have version 11.2.2 but google-auth have 11.0.4 version.
They are giving conflict.
I am not able to change the version of firebase or Google Play services because they are jar files, or google-auth have latest version.
How can I handle these conflicts?

Comment: Remove the jar files and add the dependencies for Firebase and Google Play Services. Using dependencies for integrating libraries is preferred way as it becomes easy when an update is published to the library and you need to update that library.

Answer (score 0):

Use gradle dependencies,follow below links and pick the required depenency and add to your app/build.gradle file, get rid of jar files, much easier to manage dependency in future.

[Goole API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)